# Email Form Validation - Ensuring it only has one '@' symbol

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate a form to ensure that the entered email address value is in the correct format. I have everything working except checking that it only contains one '@' symbol. This is my code so far

```
var x = document.forms["registration"]["email"].value;
var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
```

Comment: I'm genuinely asking, just incase it's something you've overlooked, but does the simple HTML5 `type="email"` provide that kind of check to the input? I know it changes the keyboard layouts on mobile devices, but what kind of validation does it perform?

Comment: why not use a regex to validate the email address instead. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @Lee according to the w3c, the user agents should implement email validation: "The user agent should act in a manner consistent with expecting the user to provide a single e-mail address" [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#e-mail-state-(type=email)). However, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation), some browsers do not currently support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check and validate for single '@'. The below mentioned one is the standard Email Regex which is been used:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

Comment: How can I use this to also check for the domain name? I need to ensure that the user is registering from only one domain (e.g. peter@google.com or mary@google.com)

Comment: Your question did not merely covered the domain section. See your question. I covered your first point that it will not take more than one '@'. Post it in new question.

Comment: Okay sorry, Is there a quick way I can add a section to my code to check for double '@' symbols? or regex the only sensible way? considering I also need to check the domain

Comment: See the regex for domain (^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$). u need to match a pair with checking only one @. I suggest to use javascript for matching both

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this to validate email: 
    ^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex

> var atpos = (x.match(new RegExp("@", "g")) || []).length;